# Is there a way to overwrite the assignment operator for a Rust type?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

My problem is the following: I'd like to set up a primitive-like struct with a more limited value range. As in

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct MyLimitedInt {
  v: i8,
}
```

but ensuring that `v`'s value is always between `-10` and `10`. I know that I can implement `std::ops` traits in order to check the value on addition etc., but there does not seem to be a way of constructing an instance of `MyLimitedInt` in a primitive-like way while still checking bounds (as in `let my_v: MyLimitedInt = -12;`, which should limit the value to `-10`).

In C-like languages I could probably do that by overwriting the type's `=` operator, but is there a way to achieve a similar result in Rust without requiring more verbose constructors or setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator can't be overloaded in Rust. However, you can overload other operators or use methods instead - for example:

```
use std::cmp::{min, max};

#[repr(transparent)]
struct MyLimitedInt {
  v: i8,
}

impl MyLimitedInt {
  pub fn from_clamped(value: i8) -> Self {
    Self { v: min(10, max(value, -10))
  }

  /// Sets the value of the int, constraining it to the range [-10, 10]
  pub fn set_clamped(&mut self, value: i8) {
    *self = Self::from_clamped(value);
  }
}
```

This can be extended with overloads for the arithmetic operators to make it usable more like primitives:

```
use std::ops::Add;

impl Add for MyLimitedInt {
  type Output = Self;

  fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
    Self::from_clamped(self.value + other.value)
  }
}

impl Add<i32> for MyLimitedInt {
  type Output = Self;

  fn add(self, other: i32) -> Self {
    Self::from_clamped(self.value + other.value)
  }
}
```

This would make it possible to use the addition operator with `MyLimitedInt`, clamping the result automatically:

```
let x = MyLimitedInt::from_clamped(20) + 5; // 10
let y = MyLimitedInt::from_clamped(-20) + x; // 0
```

Comment: Sure, that's the way I would implement it right now. But I was mainly wondering if there are ways to make such assignments look more like handling a primitive type. Also a nitpick on your choice of function naming: on a `try_x` function I would usually expect a `Result`-type return, in this case I would probably call the function simply `set` or maybe `set_checked`

Comment: I'd call it `set_clamped` or `set_saturating`, FWIW. (Compare [`saturating_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.saturating_add))

Comment: @Sty I've added an example on how to use other overloadable operators to make it a bit more natural - is this closer to what you wanted?

Comment: @apetranzilla again, I knew about that (and explicitly stated so in the question), which is why I was mainly focusing on `=` operator functionality. I know it can't be overloaded by a trait, and I'll accept an answer that states "it can't be done and here's why". I guess I was mainly hoping for some more obscure way to be able to call such a `from_clamped` function directly as part of (or immediately and automatically following) a primitive value assignment somehow.